# Show object creation (from DAL) in UML sequence chart

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have 3 classes: Controller, DAL and Entity.  The controller calls the DAL requesting an Entity.  The DAL retrieves the entity data from the DB and creates a new Entity class which is then returned to the Controller.  How do I show this on a UML sequece chart (no need to show the DB)?

2nd question: how should we share UML diagrams on SO? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean that the DAL creates an Entity "Object"?

Comment: Yes, the DAL creates the Entity object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   Controller       DAL               DB
        |            |                 |
        | get entity |                 |
        |----------->| get entity data |
        |            |---------------->|
        |            |< - - - - - - - -|
        |            |                 |
        |            |--               |
        |            |  |create entity |
        |            |<-               |
        |<- - - - - -|                 |
```

note: "Create entity" is a "self-message", so it starts from DAL's lifeline and goes back into DAL's lifeline. I just can't draw it better with characters. Forward messages are continous line, reply messages are dashed line.

EDIT: reflecting on comment, you can also show Entity's lifeline, if it's important.

```
   Controller       DAL               DB
        |            |                 |
        | get entity |                 |
        |----------->| get entity data |
        |            |---------------->|
        |            |< - - - - - - - -|
        |            |                 |
        |   entity   |---->Entity      |
        |<- - - - - -|       |         |
        |            |       |         |
```

It's useful if you want to show other calls to Entity as well.

Comment: Nice one.  You could 'dash' the lines by using spaces between the dashes (---- vs - - - -)

You can add a fourth lifeline starting level with the "create entity" call, representing the lifetime of the "Entity" object.

Comment: Would you not also added the Entity onto this diagram, showing a line from the DAL to the Entity with some time spent at the Entity to indicate object construction?